# Search across multiple cores and get unified result

Tags: solr

I have 2 cores on a single solr instance. Schema's of both cores share same primary key.
I want to merge results of a query from both the cores. Is it possible using solr?

I followed [Solr:Distributed Search](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch)  however the example didnt work for me ( I did get result but it was not unified) . I queried solr cores using :

> localhost:8983/solr/core1/select/?shards=localhost:8983/solr/core1,localhost:8983/solr/core0&q=123_456.

Has anyone tried this approach before?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by Unified results ??
You should be able to get a combined results from both the Cores in a single result set.
However, there are few [limitations](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch#Distributed_Searching_Limitations).
The schema needs to same for both the cores or has been synced up so that the search happens on the same fields and are returned accordingly.

What do mean cores share same primary key ?
The Id needs to be unique across cores.

> The unique key field must be unique across all shards. If docs with
>   duplicate unique keys are encountered, Solr will make an attempt to
>   return valid results, but the behavior may be non-deterministic.

Comment: Well, the scenario is i have id,field1,field2 in one schema and id,field3,field4 in another schema. Is it possible to get result as id,field1,field2,field3,field4? Or am i trying to get something that is not even supported? (it is more like a database join)

Comment: If you want it as a single record, Sharding is not a way to go. Check for dataimport handler where you can join the tables and create single record.

Comment: @DeeptiBhosale Hi, I come across the same case, do you solve it?