# SOLR is not searching across all SHARDS

Tags: solr

I have created one node(shrd1) in solr and created one core inside that and run the below command

> ..solr-5.1.0\bin>solr.cmd -s solr/shrds/shrd1 -p 8886 -f

and import data which is having id and name as field and query the same and it is working fine.

Then I created another node(shrd2) in solr and created one core inside that and run the below command

> ..solr-5.1.0\bin>solr.cmd -s solr/shrds/shrd2 -p 8887 -f

and import data which is having id and name as field and query the same and it is working fine.

Now was trying for distributed search, so tried below thing browser,

> http://localhost:8887/solr/souro_core2/select?q=name:souro&indent=true&shards=localhost:8886/solr/souro_core1,localhost:8887/solr/souro_core2

(Both shards are having name souro, so it should return result two right?)
But instead of returning two result, result is only from one shard.

Can you please let me know what I am missing? Why i am not getting result from all shards why i am only getting from one shards?

P.S. - I have followed below link for the same,

> https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Distributed+Search+with+Index+Sharding

Comment: I think you should use SolrCloud for sharding - from the link you gave: "It is highly recommended that you use SolrCloud when needing to scale up or scale out. The setup described below is legacy and was used prior to the existence of SolrCloud."

Comment: I know but before that i was trying to achieve this without using cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got my answer. In both shards there was an "id" field and both were containing value 1.
But after doing bit research i found out that,

**The Id needs to be unique across cores. The unique key field must be unique across all shards. If docs with duplicate unique keys are encountered, Solr will make an attempt to return valid results, but the behavior may be non-deterministic.**

> Link:
>   [Search across multiple cores and get unified result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11679665/search-across-multiple-cores-and-get-unified-result?rq=1)

In my case it was returning only one result. I changed id's value and got the result as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
http://localhost:8887/solr/souro_core2/select?q=name:souro&indent=true&shards=shard1,shard2
```

That should work 
If you have collection with name souro_core2 which has two shard.

Comment: It is not working because of the obvious reason that i have not given shards their logical name as shard1 and shard2.
But how it is different instead of name i have given shard's actual details(like host:port ..).